# Report transition from Access to Crystal (multiple queries)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have just started a new job where I am responsible for building and improving reports.

There is one report I am trying to move from Access to Crystal.  The data is stored in an application called Acctivate.  The previous person who held my job built the report with a series of queries that built multiple tables, and then a final query which aggregated the information from the tables built by the first five queries.

The PTB want the report in Crystal so the management for each client can call up their info and run the report, rather than have to call me and have me do it.

What is the best approach to this multi-level query (currently make-table) that will let me move the report out of Access?

Comment: What data store will you be using going forward?

Comment: Reporting tools by definition cannot create or load table structures.  Access is not a reporting tool by definition, it is an RDBMS.  You will need some external tools or scripts to handle that part or you can still use Access to handle the data loading.  Is the data source still going to be an access database or are you migrating the data out as well?

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin not sure i agree with your statement. A report can issue an embedded query or execute a stored proc which could create or populate tables. (Temporary or permanent)

Comment: @Sir Swears-a-lot A stored proc would require an RDBMS.  The question implies using Crystal to directly manipulate data to load tables similar to Access which isn't possible.  Crystal, at least the versions I've used will not allow a sprok if it issues update or insert statements. Regardless, that would require an RDBMS which we still don't know.

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin yes you are right. I was getting a bit ahead of myself. Im assuming there is an rdbms behind the scenes.

Comment: Acctivate is the company's core app, it handles sales, POs and inventory; it has a SQL Server back end.  The current MS Access database is also connected to it.

What they want for me to do is create a Crystal Report that the managers can run themselves.  Right now, if someone wants a report out of the Access database, they have to email me and tell me what they want.

As I said in my question, there are about 25 make table queries in the Access database.  I assumed I would have to write views/stored procedures to transition the data process to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a SQL Server backend you have a few options depending how much freedom you have to add objects to the application db or on the server.

If you are not permitted to add objects to the native schema i would request a small report db on the same server where you can create views or stored procs that reference the source database schema using 3 part names.

If you can re-write the query and deploy it as a view that might be a good option.  If the query is too complex to be rewritten as a single query then you could reproduce the behavior of "make tables" with temorary #tables and deploy it as a stored procedure.

If you arent permitted to create objects on the server at all i would rewrite the query using #tables and embed the whole thing in the report query.

Views and SP's get better performance as the number of users/hits increase compared to embedded queries.